# Open div and close all others and change arrows onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a filter sidebar on my website with different categories that are all hidden at first. When you click on a categorie the options show and the arrow next to the categorie changes from down to up. This works

When you click on the next categorie the other categorie(s) should close. This works too.

What doesn't work is that the arrows of the categories that are closing change back to down (they stay up).

Besides that I think my code is way to big, there should be an easier way with $this but I can't find the right solution. Hopefully somebody can help me!

https://jsfiddle.net/mxqp4c4h/14/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.filterdropdown").each(function() {
    var a = $(this);
    $(".dropdowntitle", a).click(function(i) {
      return i.preventDefault(), $div = $(".dropdowncontent", a), $div.toggle(), $("div.dropdowncontent").not($div).hide(), !1
    })
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.filterdropdown").each(function() {
    var a = $(this);
    $(".dropdowntitle", a).click(function(i) {
      return i.preventDefault(), $div = $(".fa-chevron-down", a), $div.toggle(), $("div.fa-chevron-down").not($div).hide(), !1
    })
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.filterdropdown").each(function() {
    var a = $(this);
    $(".dropdowntitle", a).click(function(i) {
      return i.preventDefault(), $div = $(".fa-chevron-up", a), $div.toggle(), $("div.fa-chevron-up").not($div).hide(), !1
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify with just using JS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdowntitle").click(function(i) {
    
    var thisEle = $(this).parent().find(".dropdowncontent");
    var oriVisible = false;  
    if (thisEle.is(":visible")) {
      oriVisible = true;
    }
    
    // Reset
    $(".dropdowncontent").hide();
    $(".fa-chevron-down").show();
    $(".fa-chevron-up").hide();
      
    if (oriVisible) {
    // do nothing
    } else {

      thisEle.show();
      $(this).find(".fa-chevron-down").hide();
      $(this).find(".fa-chevron-up").show();
    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.clear { display:block; }
.filter { position:relative; width:100%; display:inline-block; clear:both; }
.dropdowntitle { position:relative; width:100%; display:inline-block; clear:both; }
h1 { padding:0; margin:0; float:left; }
i.fa {float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="filter filterdropdown">

  <div class="dropdowntitle">
    <h1>Style</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" style="display:none;"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdowncontent" style="display:none;">
    A
  </div>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="filter filterdropdown">

  <div class="dropdowntitle">
    <h1>Accomodation type</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" style="display:none;"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdowncontent" style="display:none;">
    B
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this with a little bit of css, example below

HTML:

```
<div class="filter filterdropdown js-accordion-item">
    <div class="dropdowntitle js-accordion-item-title">
        <h1>Style</h1>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdowncontent">A</div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="filter filterdropdown js-accordion-item">
    <div class="dropdowntitle js-accordion-item-title">
        <h1>Accomodation type</h1>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdowncontent">B</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.filter .fa-chevron-up { display: none; }
.filter .dropdowncontent { display: none; }

.filter.active .fa-chevron-up { display: block; }
.filter.active .fa-chevron-down { display: none; }
.filter.active .dropdowncontent { display: block; }
```

JS:

```
function initializeAccordions() {
    $(".js-accordion-item").on("click.accordionItem", ".js-accordion-item-title", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $accordionItem = $(this).closest(".js-accordion-item");
        if ($accordionItem.hasClass("active")) {
            $accordionItem.removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $accordionItem.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(initializeAccordions);
```

Fiddle link: http://jsbin.com/fukusit/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).on("click", ".question-div", function() {
    $(".answer-div").hide();
    $(".fa").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find(".answer-div").toggle();
    $(this).find(".fa").toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.question-div-span {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  color: #000 !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
}

.answer-div {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: none;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.fa {
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.fa.active {
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!--1-->
    <div class="main-div">
      <div class="question-div">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="question-div-span"> Style </span>
      </div>
      <div class="answer-div">
        A
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--2-->
    <div class="main-div">
      <div class="question-div">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="question-div-span"> Accomodation type </span>
      </div>
      <div class="answer-div">
        B
      </div>
    </div>
```